# Accessing the paths of a Snakemake workflow's conda environments in rule inputs/outputs *without hardcoding*?

Tags: conda, snakemake

I've got a Snakemake workflow which requires two separate conda environments, and one rule potentially downloads files and saves them into directories in the conda environment's path if they're missing (if you're curious: primer schemes and medaka models being automatically downloaded in the ARTIC pipeline). To avoid issues when multiple instances of that rule are run simultaneously for the first time in a new environment, I've inserted other rules to check for the presence of these files and pre-download them if needed (by having them be prerequisites of the offending rule).

Currently, I'm handling this with checkfiles, but I've been wondering if there was a way to access the paths of the various conda environments Snakemake is using within the Snakefile, equivalent to `$CONDA_PREFIX` in the shell, so I could check for the files directly? (Finding the environment with `--list-conda-envs` and hardcoding it isn't really an option, as it's supposed to be portable.)

**EDIT**: @dariober's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68662466/15704972) nudged me into working out a workaround for *this* case - working out that `artic minion` *could* take a path for the `--medaka-model` argument and downloading the model somewhere less irritating to work with - and that's solved it (thanks!), but I still wonder: *is* there something, for example somewhere in `snakemake.conda`, that one could use to get at a Snakemake-created conda environment's path without having to find and hardcode it in a case where there's no such workaround?

Answer (score 0):

> one rule potentially downloads files and saves them into directories in the conda environment's path

In my opinion, saving files in the conda directory is a poor design choice. If possible I would avoid that. However, assuming you don't want or cannot do that, maybe you should have a rule to create the conda environment. In this way you can tell via  `$CONDA_PREFIX` where the conda environment is. E.g.:

```
rule create_env:
    output:
        touch('conda_env.done'),
    shell:
        r"""
        conda create -n my-env ...
        """

rule download_files:
    input:
        'conda_env.done',
    output:
        # Some file under $CONDA_PREFIX for my-env
    shell:
        r"""
        conda activate my-env
        
        # Download files and put them under $CONDA_PREFIX
        ...
        """
```

By the way, snakemake creates the conda environment under the `.snakemake/conda` directory in the working directory. However, I think it's going to be messy to find out which conda environment directory is the one you need.

Comment: Just so I'm not missing something: there's still no way of having Snakemake use that environment I'd create with `conda:` if I go that route, is there? I know there was a suggestion for that possibility to be added but it didn't look like anything moved there, and having to start half of my code with `conda activate` feels a bit like it defeats the point of `use-conda`...

Comment: (Re: finding the env and using that, as far as I can tell Snakemake still incorporates the absolute path to the target env dir into the hash, right? I'd rather like to avoid that since it's meant to run on different machines without having to work that out every time, and on top of that the environment will have to change from time to time (some packages are definitions of coronavirus lineages and the like) so even on one machine I'd have to keep redoing it.)

Comment: *having to start half of my code with conda activate feels a bit like it defeats the point of use-conda* Sure it's not great but it's roughly equivalent to having half of your rules include `conda: "my-env.yaml"`. Snakemake is going to issue `conda activate` anyway. I cannot think of better options...

Comment: I ended up finding a workaround that avoids having to save anything into the conda environment now - here's to hoping the tool I've been using won't get an update that breaks it...